# Best way to correlation coefficient foe nominal data similarity

Tags: cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, similarity, cosine-similarity

I hope someone can help me on this one (PLEASE) :
I want to do similarity between some article features ( author,  category, year, impact factor , citation) 
And I dont have a clue how to do it for the nominal data , for the numerical features I can do the cosine similarity but how can I do it for the nominal  ? 
Thanks in advance for everybody !

Answer (score 0):

While I don't want to recommend this approach, it seems to be very popular:

encode your categories as binary attributes. i.e.:

```
A1=Car   ->  (1,0,0)
A1=Truck ->  (0,1,0)
A1=Bike  ->  (0,0,1)
```

then you can continue as you would with text. This is effectively the same as treating them as three different words.

It will work, but IMHO there is just no notion of "correlation" outside of continuous numerical values. Already on text it is more of a hack to make things than a good approach.